# Should I remove one partition before installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have more than one partition (4). Should I remove some before partitioning to fit Ubuntu (windows 8)?

I am keen to dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 onto my windows 8 HP laptop. I would like to install it onto USB, then boot it up and try it then give the OS its own partition.

Is it safe to have more than four partitions and then add a fifth? I am not a particularly 'techy guy, so laymens terms please!

Answer (score 1):

The 4-partition limit is an issue on disks that use the old [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system. Computers that ship with Windows 8 almost invariably use the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), which has a much higher limit -- 128 partitions by default, although that can be raised with the right software. (Even MBR-based disks can have more than four partitions, but one of the four *primary* partitions must be an *extended* partition, which in turn can hold an arbitrary number of *logical* partitions. Getting this set up on a system that already has four primary partitions can be a pain.)

If you've re-installed Windows, or if your system came with Windows 7 and you subsequently upgraded to Windows 8, it's conceivable you'll have to deal with MBR's 4-primary-partition limit. If you want to be 100% sure of what you've got, you can check your partition table type, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#windows)

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to have the number of partitions you have. Just make sure you have enough free space for your Ubuntu installation. It is good idea to have >= 10 GB free somewhere. 
If you are manually partitioning during installation, you would be allocating this space to /, /home and /boot mount points and perhaps some others. Again you can have as many of these, apart from the three necessary ones, as you want.

As you are dual booting with Windows 8, you might not be able to access these ntfs partitions right away from Ubuntu. In that case refer to this: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score -2):

Have 4 or 5 partitions seems to me not the problem should just make sure that your pc have enough memory to do what you want to do.

If it has enough memory no problem.

Regards David